# Pegar e listar meses entre datas de anos diferentes

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho a seguinte questão. Data Inicial: 01/10/2017 e data final 01/10/2018. Como posso listar os meses entre estas datas?

Por exemplo: outubro(17), novembro(17), dezembro(17), janeiro(18)...e por ai vai até setembro(18).

Comment: vc quer por extenso o nome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue exemplo:

```
// Data de ínicio
$start    = (new DateTime('2017-10-01'))->modify('first day of this month');
// Data final
$end      = (new DateTime('2018-10-01'))->modify('first day of next month');
// Define qual será o intervalo a ser calculado
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');
// Cria o período de data entre o inicio, final e o intervalo
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

// conforme o intervalo, retorna todas datas
foreach ($period as $dt) {
   echo $dt->format("Y-m") . "<br>\n";
}
```

Teste online: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3856a4b6b1e5450bdc65acad755150f248315903

Comment: Muito bom! Isso mesmo que estava precisando, vai ajudar muito <3